# Calculate transfer function given 3dB point?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, transfer-function, laplace-transform

I'm not sure the relationship between transfer function from the 3dB point. The transfer function should give the gain, and I suppose when we put in the frequency at the 3dB point, the transfer function should be equal to a certain fraction?

Comment: The -3dB point does not uniquely determine the transfer function. If you know other information (e.g. that it's a low pass first order system) then you may be able to determine the transfer function.

Comment: Only one point of a function does not determine the most simple function: A straight line.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot calculate the transfer function given one point on its bode plot namely the 3dB point. How would you know what it did at DC or HF - you don't know if it's a low pass, high pass or bandpass filter. You can't even tell how many orders the filter has.

Here are a low pass and a high pass filter having the same 3dB point as an example: -

[image]

If all you measured was the 3dB point you wouldn't know which filter it was. Here is a bandpass filter: -

[image]

Which 3dB point are you measuring or have knowledge of?